# Sed inside jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, sed, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to run the below in jenkins and i get  error any suggestions?

```
     sh ''' sed -i \':a;N;$!ba;s/\\n/\\|\\#\\|/g\' ${concl} '''
```

Error - Why isnt the `${concl}` being repalced with filename inside the shell script?

```
   + sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\|\#\|/g'
    sed: no input files
```

Comment: Can you paste what the `sed` command look like when it runs successfully in the command line? If we know what your command does it will be much easier to help you solving the problem.

Comment: sed -i ':a;N;$\!ba;s/\n/\|\#\|/g'   temp.txt

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would suggest running bash command in double quotes and escape `$` and `\` character. Consider following Jenkins pipeline exemplary script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Inital content of temp.txt file'
                sh 'cat temp.txt'

                sh "sed -i ':a;N;\$!ba;s/\\n/\\|\\#\\|/g' temp.txt"

                echo 'Content of temt.txt file after running sed command...'
                sh 'cat temp.txt'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `temp.txt` file I use in this example contains:

```
lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet

12 13 14

test|test
```

When I run it I get following console output:

```
Started by user admin
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test-pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
[Pipeline] echo
Inital content of temp.txt file
[Pipeline] sh
[test-pipeline] Running shell script
+ cat temp.txt
lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet

12 13 14

test|test

[Pipeline] sh
[test-pipeline] Running shell script
+ sed -i :a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\|\#\|/g temp.txt
[Pipeline] echo
Content of temt.txt file after running sed command...
[Pipeline] sh
[test-pipeline] Running shell script
+ cat temp.txt
lorem ipsum|#|dolor sit amet|#||#|12 13 14|#||#|test|test|#|
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

After running the script `temp.txt` file changes its contents to:

```
lorem ipsum|#|dolor sit amet|#||#|12 13 14|#||#|test|test|#|
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, i failed to understand the error it was throwing was w.r.t to the "$" in side the sed and not the $ for the variable , i was trying to escape the $ of the variable ignoring the intial occurrence.. I understood it now.. Thanks very much

Answer (score 6):

This is not related to `sed` but to string interpolation in Groovy. Variables (`${variable}`) will not be replaced within single-quoted strings, only within double-quoted ones.

Thus, replace `sh ''' ... '''` with `sh """ ... """` or maybe just with `sh ".."` as you have only one line or maybe with some Groovy/Java call.

Comment: It might also be worth noting that any use of $ inside double quotes not intended reference a variable needs to be escaped.

Comment: I tried this but i still get error   sh " sed -i \':a;N;$!ba;s/\\n/\\|\\#\\|/g\' \${concl} "

Comment: As in my earlier comment above, i was not escaping the first occurrence of "$" instead concentrating on the "$" at the input file .. that was issue.. Thank you for helping me out.. appreciate it